# Error handling in ASHX code

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I created an ASHX file and use it to handle async file uploads.
Since the site might not be hosted on our servers, I want to check for write permissions and delete permissions and supply the end user (site content editor in this case) with an error they can deal with.

I'm using uploadify for the upload, I'm not sure, but I`m guessing this complicates the return of a message that can be shown on the page, but maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the c# code in ashx file to check for permissions on the directory and returned different status codes as JSON objects.

```
context.response.write("{success: 'false', message: '" + ex + "'}")
```

And in the client side JS I just access response.message if response.success = false.
Everything works well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Before the user is able to attempt an upload, trying writing and reading a small file to the destination on the server (on the server side), if this fails then you can supply them with an appropriate message.